# ImportError: cannot import name 'engine' from partially initialized module 'wasmer'

Tags: python, webassembly

I just installed wasmer and wasmer cranelift using these:

```
pip install wasmer
pip install wasmer-compiler-cranelift
```

I have copied a sample script from examples folder in this library

```
from wasmer import engine, wat2wasm, Store, Module, Instance
from wasmer_compiler_cranelift import Compiler

wasm_bytes = wat2wasm(
    """
    (module
      (type $sum_t (func (param i32 i32) (result i32)))
      (func $sum_f (type $sum_t) (param $x i32) (param $y i32) (result i32)
        local.get $x
        local.get $y
        i32.add)
      (export "sum" (func $sum_f)))
    """
)
engine = engine.Universal(Compiler)

store = Store(engine)

module = Module(store, wasm_bytes)

instance = Instance(module)

sum = instance.exports.sum
results = sum(1, 2)

print(results)
assert results == 3
```

On running this script I get this error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'engine' from partially initialized module 'wasmer'
```

Am I missing something here?

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wasmer.py", line 1, in <module>
    from wasmer import engine, Store, Module, Instance
  File "F:\Projects\python-projects\wasmer.py", line 1, in <module>
    from wasmer import engine, Store, Module, Instance
ImportError: cannot import name 'engine' from partially initialized module 'wasmer' (most likely due to a circular import) (F:\Projects\python-projects\wasmer.py)
```

Comment: Please provide full traceback

Comment: You cannot use `wasmer.py` as the name of your source file, because then when Python tries to `from wasmer import`, it will try to use your own source file again instead of the library you just installed.

Comment: Now this is coming
raise ImportError("Wasmer is not available on this system")
ImportError: Wasmer is not available on this system

Comment: I tried copying and pasting that into a search engine (with quotes) and got to [the issue tracker](https://github.com/wasmerio/wasmer-python/issues) as the first result. Stack Overflow is not tech support, and you are expected to make some attempt to [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) by yourself.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I myself have created that issue, check the author.